# копирование строки в ассемблере без счётчика

Tags: ассемблер

Не могу понять как сделать, изучаю ассемблер. Создаю две локальные переменные. В одну записываю строку из четырех байт. нужно скопировать из этой строки в другую без счётчика. проверять нужно только байт на ноль. если байт равен нулю, то циклю копирования закончить. и вот проблема. если я загружу в `esi [ebp - 0x17]`, то загрузится значение, а не адрес. и ещё нельзя делать так `mov byte [ebp + edx], al`. в общем вот код, посмотрите пожалуйста.

```
  1 section .text
  2 
  3 global _start
  4 
  5 dd:
  6         push ebp
  7         mov ebp, esp
  8         sub esp, 0x28
  9         mov dword [ebp - 0x17], 0x34333231
 10         mov word [ebp - 0x13], 0x0
 11 
 12         cld
 13         mov esi, [ebp - 0x17]
 14         mov ecx, 0x19
 15 ;       mov edi, [ebp - 0x19]
 16 loop:   
 17         lodsb
 18         mov byte [ebp - ecx], al
 19         inc ecx
 20         test al, al
 21         jnz loop
 22         leave
 23         retn
 24 
 25 _start: 
 26         push ebp 
 27         mov ebp, esp
 28         and esp, 0xfffffff0
 29         call dd
 30 
 31         mov eax, 1
 32         mov ebx, 0
 33         int 0x80
 34         ret
 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, вроде работает.

```
  1 section .text
  2 
  3 global _start
  4 
  5 dd:
  6         push ebp
  7         mov ebp, esp
  8         sub esp, 0x28
  9         mov dword [ebp - 0x17], 0x34333231
 10         mov word [ebp - 0x13], 0x0
 11 
 12         cld
 13         lea esi, [ebp - 0x17]
 14         mov ecx, 0x19
 15 ;       mov edi, [ebp - 0x19]
 16 loop:
 17         lodsb
 18         mov byte [ebp + ecx], al
 19         inc ecx
 20         test al, al
 21         jnz loop 
 22         leave
 23         retn
 24 
 25 _start:
 26         push ebp
 27         mov ebp, esp
 28         and esp, 0xfffffff0
 29         call dd
 30 
 31         mov eax, 1
 32         mov ebx, 0
 33         int 0x80 
 34         ret
```